# Get email Address from CSV file line and send email to each of them separately

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file, i want to send email separately to each user, currently from my script i am getting emails to all users addresses those are in my csv file "user" column. Here is my CSV file Data.

```
    #TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"time","remip","user","msg"
"11:12:15","124.29.228.164","abc@xyz.com.pk","SSL tunnel shutdown"

"11:12:43","124.29.228.164","efg@gmail.com","SSL tunnel established"

"11:13:25","124.29.228.164","abc@xyz.com.pk","SSL tunnel established"

"11:14:05","202.63.194.8","efg@gmail.com","SSL tunnel established"
```

This is my powershell code

```
$Subject = " Alerts $(get-date -Format "dddd MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm")"
$Server = "qs42.xyz.com"
$From = "logalerts@abc.com"
$To = $ID = Import-Csv myfile.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty user -Unique

$PWD = ConvertTo-SecureString "test123" -AsPlainText -force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("logalerts@abc.com" , $pwd)

    $path = "myfile.txt"   
$file = (Import-Csv $path)  | Select-Object -Unique -Property Time , remip , user , Msg


    Send-MailMessage -From $from -to $To -Port 587 -SmtpServer $server -Subject $Subject -Credential $cred -UseSsl -Body ($file | Out-String)
```

Iam able to get emails of this data on both address abc@xyz.com, efg@gmail.com which i dont want, i know emails are receiving because of my variable setting but my requirement is to get emails of each user data on the same user email address.

```
>>time     remip          user                    msg                  
----     -----          ----                    ---                  
11:12:15 124.29.228.164 abc@xyz.com     SSL tunnel shutdown  


11:12:59 124.29.228.164 efg@gmail.com SSL tunnel shutdown  

11:13:25 124.29.228.164 abc@xyz.com     SSL tunnel established

11:14:05 202.63.194.8   efg@gmail.com SSL tunnel established
```

I don't know how to do this any help please.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to send email to each user with data corresponding only with their email address?

Comment: yes Exactly ....

Comment: Try this in the last line: `$To | %{ $CurrentReciepient = $_; Send-MailMessage -From $from -to $To -Port 587 -SmtpServer $server -Subject $Subject -Credential $cred -UseSsl -Body ($file | ? $_.user -EQ $CurrentReciepient | Out-String) }`

Comment: its not working and giving error   ```Where-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:15 char:167```

Comment: The fourth line of your code, where you assign a value to $To is simply incorrect.  You cannot assign a value to $To outside the main loop.  You need to assign a value to $To that depends on the data in the current CSV record.

Answer (score 2):

There were a couple of things wrong with your code:

- `$PWD` is an automatic variable and means the current working directory. You must not use that name as self-defined variable
- You use `Import-Csv` multiple times where once is enough
- The way you try to get a value in the `$To` variable is wrong
- you need `Group-Object` because some users may have more than one message
- I'd recommend using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) the parameters to the Send-MailMessage cmdlet

Try:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "test123" -AsPlainText -force
$cred     = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("logalerts@abc.com" , $password)

# import the data from the csv, group on field 'user' (which is the emailaddress to send to)
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\myfile.txt' | Group-Object user | ForEach-Object {
    # build a Hashtable to neatly send the parameters to Send-MailMessage cmdlet
    # this is called Splatting.
    $mailParams = @{
        From       = 'logalerts@abc.com'
        To         = $_.Name  # the Name of the group is from the user field in the csv
        Port       = 587
        SmtpServer = 'qs42.xyz.com'
        Subject    = 'Alerts {0:dddd MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm}' -f (Get-Date)
        Credential = $cred
        UseSsl     = $true
        Body       = $_.Group | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
    }

    Send-MailMessage @mailParams
}
```

Comment: Your answer is better than the answer I was working on.  IN ADDITION, the CSV file itself has a major flaw.  The first line, containing the #TYPE is incorrect.  # indicates a comment in the CSV file, but it MUST be in column 1.  There can be NO spaces before it.

Comment: Splatting was a very good idea for clarifying the code and making it easier to read.

Comment: @WalterMitty Thanks. Yes, the spaces in front of the comment line `#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` should not have been there. Without these (or better still without that line as a whole) Import-Csv loads the data just fine. Obviously, that file was created using `Export-Csv` without the `-NoTypeInformation` flag. I'm assuming that the OP added those spaces while posting here. (same goes for all the empty lines in between the data and the `>>` in front of the first field in his second try.)

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the answer given by @theo, but it doesn't use the Group-Object cmdlet. I've had problems with memory consumption when the data set is very large because it stores structures (PSObject or PSCustomObjects) within objects and the objects tend to be pretty large.

```
$PassWord = ConvertTo-SecureString "test123" -AsPlainText -force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("logalerts@abc.com" 
, $PassWord)

$path = "myfile.txt"
# Get all alerts
$Alerts = Import-Csv $path  | Select-Object -Unique -Property Time , remip , user 
, Msg
# get individual recipient addresses from the log file
$UniqueUsers = $Alerts |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty user -Unique

ForEach ($User in $UniqueUsers){
    $UniqueAlerts = $Alerts |
                         Where-Object {$_.user -eq $User}
    $params = @{
        From       = 'logalerts@abc.com'
        To         = $User
        Subject    = 'Alerts {0:dddd MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm}' -f (Get-Date)
        Body       = $UniqueAlerts | Out-String     # This probably won't align 
the 
columns properly
                                                # if a mono-spaced font isn't 
used by the e-mail client.
                                                # you might consider sending the 
message in HTMP format
        SmtpServer = 'qs42.xyz.com'
        Port       = 587
        UseSsl     = $true
        Credential = $cred
    }
    Send-MailMessage @params
}
```

As noted in comments, the body of the message will probably be hard to read if it's in plain-text. A HTML message with the data within a table will produces a much easier to read message.